# Left and Right borders are missing when printing a WPF Grid directly

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, printing

I am attempting to print a WPF Grid. Inside that grid, there are labels, images, and additional grids. Below, you'll find the code executed when the user wants to print the window. I cannot share the entire XAML code because it contains sensitive information.

```
var printDlg = new PrintDialog();

if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ResultContentRowDefination.Height = new GridLength(603, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    Height = 1153;
    printDlg.PrintVisual(MainRowGrid, "Work Request");
    ResultContentRowDefination.Height = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    Height = 800;
}
```

Here is a segment showing how the window looks. You can observe a black 1-pixel border on the left of the labels.

[image: Part of the window]

This is the printout window dialog:

[image: Printout window dialog]

An interesting observation is that when I use 'Microsoft Print to PDF' and then print the saved PDF file, the borders appear. However, when selecting the printer directly from the dialog, the borders do not appear.

Here are the printed papers. On the left one, there are no borders, whereas on the right, borders are visible:

[image: Printed out papers]

I've attempted using a different printer, but it didn't work. I also tried changing the scale options in the print dialog, but that also did not work.

I expected that altering the print settings or trying different printers would resolve the problem and ensure the borders appeared consistently in the printed documents.

However, despite trying different printers and adjusting the scale options in the print dialog, the issue persisted. The borders were visible when printing from 'Microsoft Print to PDF' and then printing the saved PDF file, but they were not appearing when directly selecting a printer from the print dialog.

Comment: I understand the concept of the 'Gripper Margin.' However, I'm confused about how PDF files adjust the gripper margin to avoid printing problems, ensuring that when I print the saved PDF file using the same printer, the borders remain visible. Do I need to calculate the gripper margin in my code or is there another approach?

Comment: We'll be providing this software to customers, so I won't be able to configure the hardware settings for each customer's printer.